# Displaying array that is within an array in HTML

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, node-modules

I am trying to display information to website through. I know the information is being passed because I logged it to the console. When I try to write the HTML for it to display when writing the loop I can pass the array as a parameter but it does not display anything. I believe this is because the data I am trying to access is an array itself. In the HTML wishlist.wishlistDetail is accessing a List with the desired data to display.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WishlistDetailsService } from './wishlist-details.service';
import { IwishlistDetails } from './wishlist-details';
import { Iwishlist } from '../wishlist'
import { WishlistService } from '../wishlist.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wishlist-details',
  templateUrl: './wishlist-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wishlist-details.component.css']
})
export class WishlistDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  wishlists: Iwishlist[];
  wishlistId: number;

  constructor(private wishlistDetails: WishlistDetailsService, private wishlistService: WishlistService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params["id"] == undefined) {
        return;
      }

      this.wishlistId = params["id"];

      this.wishlistService.getWishlists(this.wishlistId.toString())
        .subscribe(wishlist => this.loadData(wishlist),
          error => console.error(error));

    })
  }

  loadData(wishlist: Iwishlist) {
    this.wishlistService.getWishlist()
      .subscribe(wishlistsfromapi => this.wishlists = wishlistsfromapi,
        error => console.error(error));
  }

}
```

```html
<table class="table" *ngIf="wishlists && wishlists.length">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
      <ng-container *ngFor="let wishlist of wishlists">
        <tr><td><h2>{{wishlist.wishlistDetails}}</h2></td></tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let details of wishlist.wishlistDetails"><td>{{details.BookId}}</td></tr>
      </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
import { IwishlistDetails } from "./wishlist-details/wishlist-details";

export interface Iwishlist {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  userId: number;
  wishlistDetails: IwishlistDetails[];
}
```

```
export interface IwishlistDetails {
  Id: number;
  WishlistId: number;
  SearchString: string;
  Quantity: number;
  BookId: number;
}
```

Console logs from within the wishlistDetails component:

```
{id: 40, name: "wishlist 2", userId: 1, applicationUser: null, details: Array(1)}
applicationUser: null
details: Array(1)
0: {id: 5, quantity: 1, wishListId: 40, bookId: 15, book: null}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
id: 40
name: "wishlist 2"
userId: 1
__proto__: Object
```

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 40, name: "wishlist 2", userId: 1, applicationUser: null, details: null}
1: {id: 43, name: "wishlist 3", userId: 1, applicationUser: null, details: null}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Model for wishlist:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace angular.Web.Models
{
    public class WishListFilter
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string SearchString { get; set; }

        public string Names { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }
    }
    public class WishList : EntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public List<WishListDetail> Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach wishlist sample data?

Comment: I see you have an interface for the wish list what does the IwishList & IwishlistDetails  interfaces look like?

Comment: Hello, I added the sample data which is shown in the console logs as well as the interfaces I used. I noticed that the console is showing 2 arrays, one of only the details and another of the entire wishlist with the wishlists as 'null' I have not been able to detect why this is happening.